# how to return a value to variable if varible path returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable and I want to return the value 0 if the original path returns as undefined.

I tried to do this with an IF statement inside the variable but this doesn't work.

Thank you for any help

```js
const balance = wallet.balance if (balance === undefined || balance === null) {  
console.log("Balance is null or undefined"); 
balance = 0;
};
```

Comment: `javascript` is not the same as `java`. I removed the irrelevant tag.

Comment: @CherryDT Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??`:

```js
const balance = wallet.balance ?? 0
```

---

Something closer to what you already wrote would be using a ternary:

```js
const balance = wallet.balance == null ? 0 : wallet.balance
```

(Note that `wallet.balance == null` with loose comparison is a shorter way to check for both `null` and `undefined` at once.)

Of course you could also write an `if`, but then it would have be at its own line - and the variable would have to be non-`const` so it can be modified:

```js
let balance = wallet.balance
if (balance == null) {  
  console.log("Balance is null or undefined");
  balance = 0
}
```